# how to use FFTW3 lib on Windows platform?

Tags: fftw

> I have tried to add -l to qt, add library to VS, load lib manually, but I still don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I installed a ubuntu, follow this with root user, it passed:

FFTW comes with a configure program in the GNU style. Installation can be as simple as:

./configure
make
make install